# How to use SQLite's built-in functions with ContentValues?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to use SQLite's built-in function datetime('now','localtime') in my Android code to save date in a database field of TEXT type. I am already able to do this in sqlite3 terminal as follows:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO test (Name, NO, date) VALUES('John', 1151, datetime('now','localtime')); 

sqlite> SELECT * FROM test;
John|1151|2017-06-23 17:38:29
```

This is fine, until I want to use the `datetime()` function with Android's ContentValues. I use it like this:

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put(Entry.NAME,nameString);
values.put(Entry.NO,noInt);
values.put(Entry.DATE,"datetime('now','localtime')");
   /// ....
getContentResolver().insert(Entry.CONTENT_URI,values);
```

Then, my listview shows everything fine, but for the date's textview I exactly see the text **`datetime('now','localtime')`** instead of the date that I expected to be saved in the database e.g. 2017-06-23 17:38:29. How can I solve this problem? Is there a way I can use built-in SQLite functions with ContentValue objects for inserting data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I solve this problem?

Do not use `insert()`. Use `execSQL()`.

> Is there a way I can use built-in SQLite functions with ContentValue objects for inserting data?

No, sorry.